# outerHTML and eventListener

Tags: javascript

I have simple code:

```js
document.getElementById("number").addEventListener('click', test);
var i = 1;
function test(event) {
    document.getElementById("number").outerHTML = '<span id="number">' + (i++) + '</span>';
}
```

```html
<span id="number">0</span>
```

But this is working only to first click. Next eventListener is not working. How is the best way to make it work?

Comment: because you replace the element

Comment: You're editing the `outerHTML` of the element your `EventListener` was bound to. It's likely that you override the Listener with that

Comment: you remove event listener when you overwrite HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using innerHTML instead of outerHTML ( the latter recreates your element; the event listener is no longer added)
    0

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("number").addEventListener('click', test);
    var i = 1;
    function test(event) {
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = i++;
    }
</script>
```

Otherwise, you can reset the event listener this way, while still using outerHTML

```
<span id="number">0</span>

<script>
    document.getElementById("number").addEventListener('click', test);
    var i = 1;
    function test(event) {
        document.getElementById("number").outerHTML = '<span id="number">' + (i++) + '</span>';
        document.getElementById("number").addEventListener('click', test);

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById("number").addEventListener('click', test);
var i = 1;
function test(event) {
    this.innerHTML = i++;
}
```

```html
<span id="number">0</span>
```

Dont use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML), it returns that DOM content and you are creating another span instead, so eventlistener is not working, to replace inner content use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this.

```js
    document.getElementById("number").addEventListener('click', test);
    function test(event) {
        var obj = document.getElementById("number");
        console.log(obj.innerHTML);
        var i = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);
        obj.innerHTML = ++i;
    }
```

```html
<span id="number">0</span>
```

No need to use `outerHTML` otherwise you need to add listen in each click

Answer (score 0):

You replace the entire element so it is new. The event was on the old "number" element and the event does not rebind itself. It makes no sense to replace the entire element when you are just updating the text. Either use innerHTML or textContent

```
function test(event) {
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = i++;
}
```

Comment: You could have edited unless your rep is too low. :)

Comment: I tried, but editing just a single char is not permitted. I had to change at least 7 chars before SO allowed me to submit the edit. That seemed a bit of an overkill :)

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the html of the element "number" inside the click leading to remove the listener again:
The following should work:

```
  <script>
        document.getElementById("number").addEventListener('click', test);
        var i = 1;
        function test(event) {
            document.getElementById("number").outerHTML = '<span id="number">' + (i++) + '</span>';
            document.getElementById("number").addEventListener('click', test);
        }
    </script>
```